# MakeFile Error for running a cpp file in ssh

Tags: c++, ssh, makefile

```
CC=g++

CFLAGS=-O0
TARGET=./problem2_cpp
OUTFILE=../output/cpp.txt

$(TARGET): problem2.o 
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) problem2.o
problem2.o: problem2.cpp
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c problem2.cpp
clean:
 rm -f *.o $(TARGET) $(OUTFILE)
run: $(TARGET)
 $(TARGET) <$(INFILE) >$(OUTFILE)
```

I am a rather simple makefile to compile,run a cpp, and output its file. But I get this odd error:

> quota_ufs: over hard disk limit (pid
>   20159, uid 58861, inum 5132792, fs
>   /home) ld: fatal: file ./problem2_cpp:
>   creation interrupted: Disc quota
>   exceeded

What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
quota_ufs: over hard disk limit (pid 20159, uid 58861, inum 5132792, fs /home)
ld: fatal: file ./problem2_cpp: creation interrupted: Disc quota exceeded
```

You have run out of disk quota on the machine you are using.  I suggest deleting old files in your directory, or contacting your (university?) help desk to have your quota increased.

Answer (score 0):

The issue doesn't come from your Makefile (even if I think that a Makefile shouldn't be executing your application but just compiling it – but that's another debate).

It looks like you're running out of disk space (`Disc quote exceeded`), therefore new files cannot be created (e.g object files).

---

`quota -v` (or something similar) would tell you more about your disk usage.

Comment: Shit, that was my worry. It is our assignment to execute it as well. We are noobs. I quess I need to clean my shit.